# How do I pass var args to an anonymous function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Is it possible to do var args for an anonymous function in Clojure?

For example, how do I turn:

```
(#(reduce + (map * %1 %2 %3)) [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])
```

into something like,

```
(#(reduce + (map * [& args])) [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This solves the problem:

```
 user> ((fn[& args] (reduce + (apply map * args))) [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])
       270
```

or

```
 user> (#(reduce + (apply map * %&)) [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])
       270
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`apply`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply) function

<strike>I'm not aware of a way to do this with the `#(...)` syntax, but here is your example using `fn`</strike>

```
((fn [& args] (reduce + (apply map * args))) [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])
```

You can use `%&` to get the rest argument in the `#(...)` form, resulting in

```
(#(reduce + (apply map * %&)) [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])
```